# Calling $(document) in other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering how I can call a `$(document)` function in another JS function. I tried this, but no luck.

```
var pathIndex;

function onFSSuccess(fileSystem) {
fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Android/data/be.z33.mobile",{create:true},gotFiles,onError);
pathIndex = fileSystem.root.fullPath+'/Android/data/be.z33.mobile/exp1_index.js';
}

function gotFiles() {
    $(document).on('pageinit', '#kunstwerken_exp1', function (event, ui) {});
}

$(document).on('pageinit', '#kunstwerken_exp1', function (event, ui) {
    var $page = $(event.target); 
    $.ajax({
        dataType:"json",
        url: pathIndex,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqHXR){
            for(var x=0; x<data.length; x++){
                data[x].id = data[x].link.replace("?","").replace("=","").replace("#","");
            }
            console.log("success:");
            console.log(data);
            $("#templateDropPoint").html($("#template").render(data));
            $("#templateDropPoint").listview("refresh");
            $("body").append($("#pagetemplate").render(data));

        },
        error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            console.log(textStatus+ " "+ errorThrown);
        }
    });

});
function onError(e){
console.log("ERROR");
console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
}

function onDeviceReady() {
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSSuccess, null);    
}


function init() {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
}
```

I also tried wrapping the `$(document)` function into another function and calling that one, but that's also unsuccessful. Calling the `$(document)` function itself is also not working. Any tips or advice?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console? Can you create a simplified fiddle?

Comment: You define a function, then never use it, please explain.

Comment: Errors:
parseerror SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
file:///android_asset/www/tst.html: Line 50 : parseerror SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Also pathIndex is undefined

Comment: I updated the code, it now contains the full script.

Comment: Looks like you have a Syntax Error to me, what's line 50?

Comment: If I'm correct it refers to "for(var x=0; x<data.length; x++){". I think this error occurs because pathIndex is undefined. It isn't undefined in the other function inside the script, so that's how I realized $(document) isn't working as planned.

Comment: Well that would make since as that line has a `<` in it but it looks syntactically correct to me. If you comment out that block does the syntax error go away? If you're getting Parse Errors, no code will be executed so `$(document)` won't run at all. Remove code until you can identify the syntax error